# Removing numbers from strings in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas, and in a column have a lot of names with numbers. How do I remove the number? example: `Andorra14`:

```
energy['Country'].head()  
1.       Afghanistan   
2.           Albania   
3.           Algeria   
4.    American Samoa    
5.         Andorra14   
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `str` attribute is your friend:

```
In [10]: energy['Country'].str.replace('\d+', '')
Out[10]: 
0       Afghanistan
1           Albania
2           Algeria
3    American Samoa
4           Andorra
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

Comment: just be careful that your numbers are not between two words using `str.replace`: if you have `American12Samoa` it will become `AmericanSamoa`. If you replace with white space then you could have `'Andorra12'` to `'Andorra '`

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be using regex:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r'\d+','')
```

From:

```
0    Afghani1stan
1        Alb3ania
2         Algeria
3  American Samoa
4       Andorra14
```

I got:

```
0     Afghanistan
1         Albania
2         Algeria
3  American Samoa
4         Andorra
```